# Jboss 7 JNDI lookup class cast exception

Tags: jboss7.x, jndi, jmx, classcastexception

I'm getting familiar with Jboss 7.
I'm writing some application to try out technologies.

So I wanted to have some simple monitoring service that will allow me to do some counter on business methods.
I wanted to access counters through `jmx` and `jndi`.
The 'counter service' is part of jmx bean. During `jmx` registration it is also registered in `jndi context`.
Then it is being used in some interceptors. 
And here problem occurs, when I want to get reference from jndi I got class cast exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.cybercom.pl.jbmon.SystemMonitorService cannot be cast to com.cybercom.pl.jbmon.SystemMonitorService
```

The reason for this i believe is that there classloaders are different.

**During service startup it is:**

```
ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.as.standalone:main" from local module loader @a4d593 ....
```

**During execution it is:**

```
ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.jboss-mon-app.ear.jboss-mon-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader
```

**JMX beans**, monitoring service and interceptor exists in same ejb module.

I finally did workaround for this, instead of going through jndi I used jmx client (https://github.com/michaljedryszka/jboss-sample-monitoring/commit/dcc4f05a4d6d50e592f0517bfe0454033f8e3659)

But still I don't know how to fix that CCE with jndi lookup.

What can You suggest?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to [create and install JBoss module](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7) with classes that are part of the **JMX mbeans**. This will cause to be loaded in same classloader for all access.
After you must add the dependency to the new module in the application, for example you can use `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file.

Comment: @MichalJedryszka you're welcome. If you think the answer is correct and helpful do not forget to accept.